# Passing parameters with the method post in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp .net mvc4 application in which i'd like to pass an object `user` as a parameter from action to other:

```
 User _u = new User();
  if (_fonction == "User")
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", _u );
  }
```

the action `Index`

```
 public ActionResult Index(User u)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

by defaut , the method is `GET`, and in this case it's works. but i'd like like to use the `Post` method so i put `[HTTPPOST]` before the `Index` action but an exception appears.

if i change to :

```
 if (_fonction == "User")
            {
                if (_is_admin == true) return RedirectToAction("Index");
                else
                {
                    Session["user"] = _u;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
                }
            }
```

and

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.user = Session["user"];
            return View(Session["user"]);
        }
```

it's works.

So what is the utility of the attribute `[HttpPost]` ?

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: You cannot perform a POST via an HTTP redirect.  Consider using session state.

Comment: The resource is not found

Comment: The point of `[HttpPost]` is to require a POST request, which is not applicable in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SLaks has pointed out, you cannot perform a POST via an HTTP redirect, which is the core problem you are having. Using Session state might be an option as suggested.

As to to your specific question:

```
So what is the utility of the attribute [HttpPost]?
```

That attribute is there for you to tell the framework that the annotated method should be used to satisfy POST requests from the client (as opposed to GET requests, which is the default). It doesn't actually change the behavior of the action, and (in your case) it doesn't change how requests are sent to the method via things like `RedirectToAction`.

The exception you received when you applied the method is most likely the result of the fact that `RedirectToAction` can only be performed on an `[HttpGet]` method. With the `[HttpPost]` attribute applied, your method will no longer be a candidate for handling a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon, if you use the MVCContrib extensions from Nuget there is an attribute that you can add to your controller, PassParametersDuringRedirect, which will allow you to do what you are trying to do.

Then you can call

```
this.RedirectToAction("Index", "User", _u);
```

with no problem.